# Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group iff $\mathbb{F}$ has a finite number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, proof-verification

I would like to know if my proof below is correct.

---

> **Problem** Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group iff $\mathbb{F}$ has a finite number of elements.

**Solution**

- If $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field and say $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert = m$, then the set of all $n \times n$ matrices, which is a superset of $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, where the elements comes from $\mathbb{F}$ has cardinality $m^{n^2}$. Hence, $\vert GL_n(\mathbb{F}) \vert < m^{n^2}$ and thereby $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group.
- If $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group, note that for every non-zero element $a \in \mathbb{F} -\{0\}$, the matrix $aI_{n \times n}\in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, where $I_{n \times n}$ is the identity matrix with the multiplicative identity along the diagonal. This means $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}) + 1$ and thereby $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field.

---

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. That was really quick!

Comment: "and thereby $GL_n(\mathbb F)$ is a finite field..." I think you mean to say "finite group" here.

Comment: Yes, Calle you are correct. I have changed it now.

Comment: It's an organizational issue rather than a factual one, but you could just show that there are inclusions of sets $\mathbb{F}^{\times} \to GL_n(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}^{n^2}$ (which you've written out above).

Answer (score 3):

Looks great. The only adjustment I'd make is to say that $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|\le m^{n^2}.$ It's certainly true that $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|<m^{n^2},$ but you haven't justified it, and the strictness isn't necessary for finiteness. That's largely an aesthetic issue, though, not a technical one.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to add that $0 \cdot I_n$ does not belong to $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ and now the strictness should hold. But either way it is not required. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, that's a perfect justification. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks. At last a well behaved, polite user on this site.

Comment: I can but try. ;-) Sorry to hear that your reception hasn't been better so far.