# why $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|\le m^{n^2}$. and $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}) + 1$?

Tags: group-theory

Taken from  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619832/show-that-gl-n-mathbbf-is-a-finite-group-iff-mathbbf-has-a-finite-num)

This user is not active for many year , so im posting my doubt here.My doubt is given below in last paragraph

> **Problem** Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group iff $\mathbb{F}$ has a finite number of elements.

**Solution**

- If $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field and say $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert = m$, then the set of all $n \times n$ matrices, which is a superset of $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, where the elements comes from $\mathbb{F}$ has cardinality $m^{n^2}$. Hence, $\vert GL_n(\mathbb{F}) \vert < m^{n^2}$ and thereby $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group.
- If $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite group, note that for every non-zero element $a \in \mathbb{F} -\{0\}$, the matrix $aI_{n \times n}\in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, where $I_{n \times n}$ is the identity matrix with the multiplicative identity along the diagonal. This means $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}) + 1$ and thereby $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field.

**Answer Box** : Looks great. The only adjustment I'd make is to say that $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|\le m^{n^2}.$ It's certainly true that $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|<m^{n^2},$ but you haven't justified it, and the strictness isn't necessary for finiteness. That's largely an aesthetic issue, though, not a technical one.

**My doubts**:

$1.$$\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}) + 1$

$2.$ why $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|\le m^{n^2}.$ ?

My attempt :  In O.P attempt it is written $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}) + 1$

I think it should be $\vert \mathbb{F} \vert \leq GL_n(\mathbb{F})$

why extra $1$ is add that will be unnessecary .

In answer box  it is written  $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|\le m^{n^2}.$
i think it should be  $\left|GL_n(\Bbb F)\right|< m^{n^2}$ because  $|GL_n(\Bbb F)|$ doesn't contain determinant zero matrix

Comment: No, consider $n=1$ then $|F|>\text{GL}_1(F)=|F|-1$.

Comment: Yes, $|\text{GL}_n(F)|<|F|^{n^2}$, correct.

Comment: okss thanks u @Sumanta

Comment: Title: what is $m$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is the cardinality of $ |\mathbb{F}|$

Comment: So you mean $|\Bbb F|=m\le |GL_n(\Bbb F)|+1$ in the title?

Comment: yes  @DietrichBurde